# Can I enable SSL in Sinatra with Thin?

Tags: ssl, sinatra, thin

I'm looking for a simple way to enable SSL in a standalone Sinatra application running via Thin without having to pass the `--ssl`, `--ssl-key-file` and `--ssl-cert-file` parameters in via the Thin command line.

Is it possible to define them directly within the Sinatra app or via a config.ru file?

I've spent several hours looking for an answer to this question, but so far have not found anything that works.

Comment: how about write the command line in a script file?

Answer (score 10):

I just spent a few hours trying to figure this one out myself.

It turns out that `Thin::Server.initialize` discards `ssl` options during its `initialization` method (it delegates to its instance of `Backend`, which immediately sets its `ssl` to `nil`, ignoring any ssl options you've passed into `Thin::Server.new`. This means you have to to set ssl options *after* you've instantiated a server.)

Here's how to do it:

```
class App < Sinatra::Base

  # ...

  def self.run!
    rack_handler_config = {}

    ssl_options = {
      :private_key_file => '/path/to/foo.key',
      :cert_chain_file => '/path/to/bar.crt',
      :verify_peer => false,
    }

    Rack::Handler::Thin.run(self, rack_handler_config) do |server|
      server.ssl = true
      server.ssl_options = ssl_options
    end
  end
end

App.run!
```

Answer (score 9):

These days (sinatra 1.4.1) `run!` accepts a block that yields server. So you can do this:

```
MyApp.run! do |server|
  ssl_options = {
    :cert_chain_file => '/path/to/bar.crt',
    :private_key_file => '/path/to/foo.key',
    :verify_peer => false
  }
  server.ssl = true
  server.ssl_options = ssl_options
end
```

Comment: Very Cool! Where are these options documented? - I can't seem to find anything other than your post!

Comment: http://rdoc.info/github/eventmachine/eventmachine/EventMachine/Connection:start_tls is apparently what's happening here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Sinatra and Thin (on Heroku) with SSL using the [Rack::SslEnforcer](https://github.com/tobmatth/rack-ssl-enforcer), doing this:

```
if production?
    require 'rack/ssl-enforcer'
    use Rack::SslEnforcer
end
```

This should be before you enable :sessions in your file.